# Windows ServiceでActiveX Controlを使う方法

Tags: c#, windows, .net, windows-services

.NET Framework 4.8 C#にてWindows Serviceを作成しています。
サードパーティのActiveX Controlの機能を利用したいのですがFormは存在しません。

下記のサイトを参照し、コントロールの利用を試行しました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531512/activex-control-without-a-form

```
var control = MyActiveXControl();
control.BeginInit();
control.CreateControl();
```

Windows Serviceを登録し、プロセスにアタッチしてデバッグを行うと、
CreateControl()でフリーズしました（デバッガで次に進みません）。
原因と考えられる点、対策などはないでしょうか？

ControlをnewするThreadは、SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);によりSTAにしてあります。

また、通常のForm Applicationで、
FormにActiveX Controlを張り付けずに上記コードを実行した場合は、
フリーズすることなく正常に動作しました。

Comment: Windows Serviceを実行するアカウントで、当該ActiveXを実行できるようレジストリ等の設定は行われているのでしょうか？

Comment: もしかしたら、[4.7 セッション 0 の分離](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/msdn10/Dd871151(v=MSDN.10)) の影響かもしれませんね。あと環境と使い方は違いますが、[Office のサーバーサイド オートメーションについて](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) のような記事もあり、ここに書かれている現象と似通ったことが発生しているかもしれません。

Comment: ヒントをありがとうございます。内容の方を確認して色々と試行してみます。

Comment: サードパーティ製のControlのため、CreateControl()内で何を実行しようとしているか調査できないのが現状です。サービスの実行ユーザーを変更しても同じ問題が起こりましたので「セッション0の分離」の可能性が高いかと思いました。

Comment: この辺 [サービスでOCXを使用したい](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/bbs/phpBB/viewtopic.php?topic=32914&forum=7), [ActiveXコントロールを使用したWindowsサービスについて](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/bbs/phpBB/viewtopic.php?topic=46144&forum=7) で書かれているように、ActiveXを使う部分をexeとして分離して起動するか、単独exeのままタスクスケジューラにユーザーログオン時に動作するモードで登録して動かすか、あたりでしょうか？