# pywin32をサーバーにサインインしないで使用する方法

Tags: python, openpyxl

pywin32をWindows Serverのタスクスケジューラーに登録して使用していますが、Serverにサインインしていないと動作してくれないため、現在はスケジュールタイミングでサーバーにサインインしております。
自動化で運用したいと考えておりますが、サインインせずに使用する手段がありましたらご教示いただきたいです。

Comment: `pywin32で何を行っているか`によりますが、こんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。[「バッチジョブとしてログオンの権利が必要」…タスクスケジューラ警告の対処方法](https://se-abeaver.com/logon-as-a-batchjob/), [タスクスケジューラで「ユーザーがログオンしているかどうかにかかわらず実行する」を指定すると実行できない。](https://www.tomsword.com/weblog/cannot-be-executed-if-run-regardless-of-whether-the-user-is-logged-on-is-specified/), [『ユーザーがログオンしているかどうかにかかわらず実行する』を選択すると実行されない](https://ootaniland.com/does-not-run-when-run-regardless-of-user-logged-on-is-selected/)

Comment: ただし、これらの記事と類似の事をやろうとしていると出来ないでしょう。[(セッション0の分離)サービスからexeを実行する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/39370/26370), [Windows 10 で動くサービスプログラムにて入力したキーコードを取得出来ません。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/73928/26370), [Windows ServiceでActiveX Controlを使う方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70441/26370)

Comment: 具体的にはどのような処理を実行しようとしていますか？タグに openpyxl が付いていますが、Excel を使おうとしているなら「サーバーサイドや非対話形式での実行はサポート外」という話もあります。参考: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/50338